# How to Pass an IList<string> to Controller using Form Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to bind my data on my model which is an IList. Here is my code on my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("fncModify", "Main", FormMethod.Post, 
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

for (int x = 0; x < Model.lstEmployeeNames.Count; x++)
         {
             @Html.HiddenFor(y=>y.lstEmployeeNames[x])
         }
```

On my model view:

```
public IList<string> lstEmployeeNames { get; set; }
```

But on my controller view, my form values always return a null value:

```
 public ActionResult fncModify(FormCollection form)
    {
        IList<string> lstResult = new List<string>();
        //this always return null
        var lstResult = form["lstEmployeeNames"];
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Main");
    }
```

What do you think I am missing here? I am planning to pass the list of strings from my Model.lstEmployeeNames to my controller.

Comment: Did you check FormCollection Method object. Are you getting any value in that using breakpoint.?

Comment: @shashank I am getting null values. I am not what I am missing here. But if the data is not a collections, the data is okay.

Comment: `y=>y.lstEmployeeNames[x]` would create elements with `name`s that have a `[number]` in the end, which are the part of the name, and you seem to be ignoring them when reading your `FormCollection`. Why are you using it anyway instead of directly mapping to a `List<string> lstEmployeeNames`?

Comment: @GSerg I didn't get your point actually. If I put the data on a different variable as an IList in razor, how will I am able to pass it via FormCollection?

Comment: @WillyDavidJr You keep your code in the view and change your controller procedure to `public ActionResult fncModify(List<string> lstEmployeeNames)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by user GSerg, I was able to pass my collection from my razor view into my controller by directly mapping the List to my ActionResult method using this code:

```
public ActionResult fncModify(List<string> lstEmployeeNames)
```

Instead of using this:

```
public ActionResult fncModify(FormCollection form)
```